# Remove DecodeJpeg from tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow, onnx

There is a [pre-train ResNet](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/2017_07/oidv2-resnet_v1_101.ckpt.tar.gz) on OpenImages dataset. I want to deploy it using TensorRT or OpenVino. To do this, I should convert this model to ONNX. But there's a problem: DecodeJpeg operator is embedded into the graph definition and ONNX does not support it.
How to replace it op on my placeholder and remove old (DecodeJpeg) nodes?

I have tried this code to replace DecodeJpeg (I still don't know how to remove old nodes):

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./oidv2-resnet_v1_101.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, './oidv2-resnet_v1_101.ckpt')

g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 299, 299, 3], name='input_images')
        
        out = tf.import_graph_def(
            g.as_graph_def(),
            input_map={"map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3": ph},
            return_elements=["multi_predictions:0"]
        )
        
        input_values = g2.get_tensor_by_name('input_images:0')
        predictions = out[0]

        predictions_eval = sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={input_values: image})
```

but it `sess.run` fails with
`Attempting to use uninitialized value import/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_5/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/beta`